# I can't display image generated as byte[]

Tags: c#, angularjs, image

My controller (ASP MVC):

```
 public FileResult getTimelineChart(DateTime tsInic, DateTime tsEnd, string typeReq = "normal")
    {
            var rep = new AfterSalesWind.Models.OM_Repository();
            var chart = rep.getTimelineChart(tsInic, tsEnd);

            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);

            return File(ms.ToArray(), @"image/png");
    }
```

Angular controller:

```
getTimelineChart = function (codSap, revStr) {
    dataService.getTimelineChart($scope.dateFilter.dt1, $scope.dateFilter.dt2, function (result) {
        $scope.imageChart = "data:image/png;base64," + result;
    });
}
```

Angular service:

```
getTimelineChart = function (tsInic, tsEnd, callback) {
    $http({
        url: '/OM_API/getTimelineChart',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            tsInic: tsInic,
            tsEnd: tsEnd
        }
    }).success(function (result, status, headers) {
        return callback(result);
    }).error(function (error) {
        return callback(error);
    });
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="row">
    <img ng-src="{{imageChart}}" width="1331" height="360" />
</div>
```

According to I have read this code should allow me display a image png.
An error is ocurred:
[image]

When I call to service the result looks like this
[image]

Where I am wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't know if it is a good solution, I just know that it works for me.

I have got display image only when it was encoded in base-64. Then I changed my reply from MVC like this:

```
 public String getTimelineChart(DateTime tsInic, DateTime tsEnd, string typeReq = "normal")
{
        var rep = new AfterSalesWind.Models.OM_Repository();
        var chart = rep.getTimelineChart(tsInic, tsEnd);

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your MVC, you are returning it as a `File` which treats it as a real file, not something that is Base 64 encoded. You can simply put it on your `ng-src`.

Comment: Ok, I have removed *"data:image/png;base64,"*. The error has disappeared but the image is not displayed =( (Also, I have tried to return *ActionResult* from MVC, and nothing...)

Comment: @robBerto don't do ajax with it.

Comment: ajax is a problem? I thought that *ng-src* directive allow to use ajax. Besides, I need display image (chart) when user presses a button, so i can't dispense with ajax, right?

Comment: no you can change the ng-src at any time - use query string values. look at the `$sce` service.

Comment: Thank you for yours replies. Now I know a little about sanitaze html code. My solution is not through $sce, but sends image as encode64 string